# Device not reporting to Windows Defender ATP

Tags: windows-defender

I ran a script to offboard the PC and onboard the PC after deleting the reg key and everything in the cyber folder using the sysInternals tools. Now that I have onboarded the PC. I have waited for just under a day. Does anyone else have any experience onboarding a PC, and how long should it take?

I have tried offboarding the PC and onboarding the PC for the second time. Furthermore, I have also tried to set the sensors to auto-start and manually starting the sensors. I have viewed the windows event logs which have said that the PC got onboarded properly.

Comment: Is there anything in the application event log?

Comment: I have checked my logs and there are nothing in the logs

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot device not reporting to Windows Defender ATP, try the following:

1. Check the device is properly configured for ATP & has the latest updates.
2. Check it's not experiencing any connectivity issues.
3. Check that ATP sensor is running and has the necessary permissions.
4. Check the device is not being blocked by any firewall or security software.
5. If all fails, try reinstalling the ATP sensor on the device.